# Missing entitlement for API HomeKit

Tags: ios, provisioning-profile, homekit

I have used [HomeKitCatalog](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/HomeKitCatalog/Introduction/Intro.html) code to communicate with Home app to execute scenes and add accessory. It works as expected in app in foreground.

When my app went to background/suspend mode, sending silent notification run scene. But it throws exception "**Missing entitlement for API**".

Is it related to provisional profile issue?  Can anyone help to move forward?

Comment: did you find the exact reason of this error?  as I am also facing same issue but not sure, is it related to background or not.

Answer (score 1):

Developer can't control HomeKit from background 
https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/22279

Comment: I'm seeing this error, but doesn't seem to be because of background control : /